# 13.04 upgrade won't boot kernel 3.8

Tags: boot, 13.04

After upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04, my Toshiba NB305 won't boot under kernel 3.8.*.  I am able to boot if I manually select kernel 3.5.* from the GRUB menu.

I tried several things that have been suggested on the forums, including uninstalling Jupiter and running Boot-Repair. Neither of these worked.

Before I ran the Boot-Repair, attempting to boot kernel 3.8 would result in dropping to a shell. Now it just hangs on a black screen after GRUB.

Here is the link that Boot-Repair returned to me for troubleshooting purposes:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5646126/

I suppose I could set my GRUB preferences to load kernel 3.5, but it would be nice to have 3.8 bootable. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Let me add that I am wondering whether 3.8 is at all bootable on my netbook with it's Intel Atom chip.

Comment: Have you tried manually reinstalling GRUB to the MBR?

Answer (score 1):

This netbook has known issues with the BIOS and tickless kernel operation; the previous kernel parameters "nohz=off highres=off" may work with the newer kernel. I'm having a similar issue with installing 13.04, but it's at least booting.

**Edit:** These are the instructions for adding the kernel parameters to grub: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/508516/comments/39

**Edit 2:** After 2 days I can confirm that this fixes the 13.04 kernel on my Toshiba NB305. When running a clean install, you need to select "install ubuntu", then press F6 for advanced options. A menu will open and the GRUB boot command will become an editable line. ignroe the menu (I think I hit ESC) and move your cursor to the right of the "--" then add " nohz=off highres=off" and press enter to boot the installer. After install you should see those options in the /etc/defaults/grub file as well.