# Will Ubuntu 13.10 work on a Toshiba NB305 NB-305 Netbook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, 13.10, toshiba

I had rather big issues with 13.04 so reverted to 12.10LTS which now is currently running. I wonder if 13.10 should run on this netbook and was unable to find and info. A list of supported hardware (which has proven to work with latest Ubuntu release) would be most useful for users interested in Ubuntu.

I think this was the issue I ran into with 13.04 as well: [13.04 upgrade won't boot kernel 3.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292933/13-04-upgrade-wont-boot-kernel-3-8)

Please post your experiences so others will know if 13.10 will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will. Working fine here. Booting time with 6 minutes is not ideal. But hey, that's why you bought a netbook in the first place, right?